# Codeigniter form->run() equivalent to form_validation->run()?

Tags: php, forms

I'm relatively new to CodeIgniter and this may be an obvious answer, but I am unable to find anything in the documentation.

I know how to use **form_validation->run()** to validate a form and run some code when it is submitted successfully. What if I wanted to do something with a form that did not require any sort of validation? Is there a **form->run()** equivalent that returns true when a user submits the form? Something like:

**page.php**

```
public function update($id)
{
    $this->load->helper('form');

    if($this->form->run())
    {
        // do some stuff after user has submitted form
    }

}
```

Comment: You only need to check if there is a $_POST.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there exists such method, but you can do it manually
For example:

```
if ( ! isset($_POST['something']))  // OR $this->input->post('something');
{
    return false //maybe?
}
else
{
    //$something = $_POST['something'];
    return true //maybe?

}
```

Answer (score 1):

A statement like this should work. You just need to check if any post data exists.

```
if ($_POST)
{
 // do something
}
```